# Export vectorized graphics from pyglet rendering

Tags: python, graphics, vector-graphics, pyglet

Exporting pyglet drawings as rasterized formats is straightforward to achieve via the `pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer()` API.

Is there a way to export the rendered image in a vectorized manner, preserving the geometric shapes that were added onto the canvas?